# How can I assign int values to const char array in my blackjack game, C

Tags: c, blackjack, const-char

I'm working on a blackjack game in C. I have three functions, one to fill the deck, one for shuffling the cards and one for dealing the cards. My problem is that I don't know how to give my cards an integer value, I need that to see who wins. I would be very grateful for some input on how to solve this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "func.h"

/*fill deck with 52 cards*/
void fillDeck(Card * const Deck, const char *suit[], const char *deck[]){

int s;
for (s = 0; s < 52; s++){
    Deck[s].suits = deck[s % 13];
    Deck[s].decks = suit[s / 13];
}
return;
}



#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "func.h"

/*shuffle cards*/
void shuffle(Card * const Deck){
int i, j;
Card temp;

for (i = 0; i < 52; i++){
    j = rand() % 52;
    temp = Deck[i];
    Deck[i] = Deck[j];
    Deck[j] = temp;
}
return;
}



#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "func.h"

/*deal cards*/
void deal(const Card * const Deck, int size, int size_1, int size_2){

int i, j, length;
char anotherCard[2];
char name1[30];
char name2[30];

printf("Name player one > ");
scanf("%s", name1);
printf("Name player two > ");
scanf("%s", name2);

printf("\nWelcome %s and %s, lets begin!\n\n", name1, name2);
getchar();

    printf("%s's card:\n", name1);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("%5s of %-8s%c", Deck[i].decks, Deck[i].suits, (i + 1) % 2 ? '\t' : '\n');
    }

    printf("\n%s's card:\n", name2);
    for (i = 2; i < size_1; i++){
        printf("%5s of %-8s%c", Deck[i].decks, Deck[i].suits, (i + 1) % 2 ? '\t' : '\n');
    }

    printf("\nDealer card:\n");
    for (i = 4; i < size_2; i++){
        printf("%5s of %-8s%c", Deck[i].decks, Deck[i].suits, (i + 1) % 2 ? '\t' : '\n');
    }
return;
}



#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "func.h"

int main(void){

Card allCards[52];
const char *suits[] = { "spades", "hearts", "diamonds", "clubs" };
char *decks[] = { "ace", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "jack", "queen", "king" };
int *values[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10 };

srand(time(NULL));

fillDeck(allCards, suits, decks, values);
shuffle(allCards);
deal(allCards, 2, 4, 6);

getchar();
return 0;
}



/*func.h*/
struct card{
    const char *suits;
    const char *decks;
};

typedef struct card Card;

void fillDeck(Card * const Deck, char *suit[], char *deck[]);

void shuffle(Card * const Deck);

void deal(const Card * const Deck, int size, int size_1, int size_2);

#endif
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem? It's not very clear.

Comment: Too much code for `"I don't know how to give my cards an integer value"`.  Where are you trying to do that?

Comment: Number the cards `0..51` and then the suit can be `card / 13` and the rank can be `card % 13`. Where suits are numbered `0..3` and ranks are numbered `0..12`.

Comment: I can't tell from his question but it's important to note that ENUMS can do this very easily since you can assign the "hidden" values that the ENUMS have behind the scene.

Comment: Or else implement a function that converts your rank `char`s to numeric values.

Comment: Use `enum`s to define the rank and suit, with string arrays used to convert index values `0...` to rank and suit names.

Comment: Your array `tables` is badly typed, it should be an array of `int`s not of pointers. Correction : `int values[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10 };`. I'm not sure this is the only error, but at least this one seems to correspond to your description.

Comment: `shuffle()` could be better.  Consider if `N` was 3 rather than 52 and `rand()` is perfect.  This code would form 3*3*3  groups with uniform results.  Yet with only 3*2*1 or 6 decks, the 27 groups cannot represent the 6 decks evenly.  Search SO for other shuffle approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you add a field to your card struct to hold the value.

```
typedef struct card {
    const char *suits;
    const char *decks;
    int value;
}
```

To assign the card the value you would use:

```
void fillDeck(Card * const Deck, const char *suit[], const char *deck[], const int *value[])
{
    int s;
    for (s = 0; s < 52; s++){
        Deck[s].suits = suit[s / 13];
        Deck[s].decks = deck[s % 13];
        Deck[s].value = value[s % 13];
    }
}
```

Then when you are determining a winner you can simply look at all the cards in their hand and sum up the values.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. I guess when I have value inside fillDeck function i need to have it in shuffle and deal function as well? I tried to implement it in shuffle but I just get errors.


<code>void shuffle(Card * const Deck, const int *value[]){

 int i, j;
 Card temp;

 for (i = 0; i < 52; i++){
  j = rand() % 52;
  temp = Deck[i];
  Deck[i] = Deck[j];
  Deck[j] = temp;
  value[j];
 }

 return;
}<code>

Comment: Yes, ideally you will add value in any place that you use deck and suit. Also, just a suggestion, I would consider renaming the array holding {"ace", "two", etc...} as the name deck or decks could be confused easily with your class Deck which holds a set of 52 cards.

Comment: I wrote `value[i] = value[j];` in my shuffle function inside the for loop but its not working. Can't I write it like that?

Comment: With the shuffle function you have written in your post you shouldn't need to use value in shuffle. When I said to use it where you used deck I was referring to the the array {"ace", "two", etc...} not to the actual deck of cards. That is why I suggested giving more unique names to your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse the program's card values with their rank - make a clear distinction between ranks `0..12` used by the program, and the cards' descriptive values.

```
//char *suitname[] = { "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Spades" };
//char *rankname[] = { "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", 
                          "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace" };

char *suitname[] = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs" };
char *rankname[] = { "Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", 
                          "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };
```

Whether "Ace" is high or low, in neither case does rank "Three" have a value of `3`. I recommend dealing (pun!) with card values `0..51` and getting the suit and rank on demand with

```
int suit = card / 13;       // range 0..3
int rank = card % 13;       // range 0..12
```

In both cases, the suit or rank is a value ranged from `0`, to suit (pun!) array indexing.

As for the ranks' score values, you can define another array like this

```
int cardvalue[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10 };
```

So you can get the card's value with

```
int value = cardvalue[card % 13];
```

And print its description with

```
printf("%s of %s", rankname[card % 13], suitname[card / 13]);
```

You can also get suit hierarchy (important in some card games) by the order you define them, as I showed.

Comment: Are you talking about the main function? I still need fillDeck, shuffle and deal function right? I changed my names after your recommendations.

Comment: If you feel you need separate functions. Filling the array is a one-liner, shuffling is scarcely more.